# ClassCastException: Main(MainActivity) cannot be cast to PlayPauseClick(Interface)

Tags: android, android-fragments, methods, interface

I'm trying to call a method from my adapter class .. but I'm getting this error :

***ClassCastException: Main(MainActivity) cannot be cast to PlayPauseClick(Interface)***

This is my method in my **Fragment**(UpdatesFragment):

```
     void imageButtonOnClick(View v, int position){
    playPause=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.playPause);
    Product m = productList.get(position);
    playPause.setImageResource(m.getPlayPauseId());
    playPause.setTag(position);
    playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Product m =(Product) productList.get(pos);
                if (paused) {
                m.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                paused=false;
                }else {
                 m.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
                 paused = true;
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
           }

        });
    }
```

This is my **Interface**(PlayPauseClick):

```
public interface PlayPauseClick{
void imageButtonOnClick(View v, int position);
}
```

And this is my **Adapter** :

```
public class FunDapter<T> extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {



protected List<T> mDataItems;
protected List<T> mOrigDataItems;
protected LongExtractor<T> idExtractor;
protected final Context mContext;
private final int mLayoutResource;
private final BindDictionary<T> mBindDictionary;
private int oddColorRes;
private int evenColorRes;
private FunDapterFilter<T> funDapterFilter;
private Filter mFilter;



public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                 BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
  this(context, dataItems, layoutResource, null, dictionary);
}


public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                 LongExtractor<T> idExtractor, BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mDataItems = dataItems;
    this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
    this.mLayoutResource = layoutResource;
    this.idExtractor = idExtractor;
    this.mBindDictionary = dictionary;

}


public void updateData(List<T> dataItems) {
    this.mDataItems = dataItems;
    this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (mDataItems == null || mBindDictionary == null) return 0;

    return mDataItems.size();
}

@Override
public T getItem(int position) {
    return mDataItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    if(idExtractor == null) return super.hasStableIds();
    else return true;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if(idExtractor == null) return position;
    else return idExtractor.getLongValue(getItem(position), position);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    final GenericViewHolder holder;
    if (null == v) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
                (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(mLayoutResource, null);
        holder = new GenericViewHolder();
        holder.root = v;


        holder.playPause=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.playPause); 

        FunDapterUtils.initViews(v, holder, mBindDictionary);

        v.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (GenericViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    final T item = getItem(position);
    showData(item, holder, position);



    Product m =(Product) mDataItems.get(position);
    holder.playPause.setImageResource(m.getPlayPauseId());
    holder.playPause.setTag(position);
    holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((PlayPauseClick)mContext).imageButtonOnClick(v, position);        
        }
    });


       return v;
    }
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Where did you initialised mContext? Please post your full code of adapter.

Comment: I'v updated my question

Comment: And again where are you setting adapter in fragment? Please update.

Comment: PlayPauseClick interface is implemented by your Fragment or Activity?

Comment: @an_droid_dev  No ,I don't know how i missed it , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View v) {
>         ((PlayPauseClick)mContext).imageButtonOnClick(v, position);        
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> MainActivity cannot be cast to PlayPauseClick

So, implement it

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements PlayPauseClick { // *** HERE *** //

    @Override
    public void imageButtonOnClick(View v, int position) {
        // TODO: Implement this
    }
```

Comment: I'v created my method in my Fragment , why even I implement this interface in my fragment i still get this CastException ? I mean should I have to do something in my MainActivity too ?

Comment: Because `mContext` cannot be a Fragment

Comment: Thanks man , but what are my options then , how can I creat this method in my Fragment

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. You've already accepted the answer here